# Creating web service with Developer Studio and create its API with API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-integration-studio

I want to create a web service with WSO2 Developer Studio but I don't know which project I have to use. My final goal is to create an API using the WSO2 API Manager and implement it passing the created web service as backend endpoint.

Do I should create an Axis2 web service, a Java Bean, or maybe another artifact?

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Axi2 web service
1.https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS320/Creating+an+Axis2+Project

Comment: For more details on Axis2 service generation  http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/06/apache-axis2-integration-eclipse/ is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Using DevStudio you can built axis2 services and JAX-WS services.

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS370/Creating+an+Axis2+Project

[2] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS370/Creating+JAX-WS+and+JAX-RS+Service+Projects

For api creation in api manager you can do it via the webconsole provided in APIManager

Answer (score 0):

You do not need developerstudio to create a webservice. Webservices can be created using an IDE/IDEA..
You can try the existing samples in WSO2AS and deploy them. Make them as BE services for the APIs which you publish from WSO2APIManager.

Comment: Do you mean IntelliJ IDEA? I want to use an Eclipse based IDE and eventually use the debugging, etc. features.

Comment: WSO2 recommends using the WSO2 Developer Studio to create Axis 2 Web Services and other WSO2 artifacts using WSO2 Developer Studio. It is Eclipse based as well as comes with the Debugging capability as well.